# How do I add a find text feature in C#?

Tags: c#, database

[Picture of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuGpS.png)

This program has a bunch of buttons of produce items. When the user clicks a button it automatically copies the bar-code of that item. For example if the user clicks the "Apples" button it will copy 43490905, aka the bar-code for apples. The user can then paste this number anywhere they want.

This produce list will get VERYY long, like 1000+ items. I don't want to navigate through all the items just to find apples.

How do I add a "Find" functionality? Like in google chrome I can just hit ctrl+f and type in apples and boom I can get all the results highlighted on the page.

Thank you.

Comment: Go through all the buttons on the page and check to see if their text contains the search string you are looking for. If it does, call the click handler of that button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience, you should choose the `TextChanged` function for your `TextBox`, or if you still want to use the button, let copy these code and paste into your `Button_Click` function

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text;
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    if (!c.Text.ToUpper().Contains((text.ToUpper())))
                    {
                       //You can set the hightlight, or anything here
                        c.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //You can set the hightlight, or anything here
                        c.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Of course, if you want to use the FIND button, you should except this button from your Button list.